# cannot use npm to install redis and moment

Tags: package-management, npm, redis

I need to use `npm` to install packages `redis` & `moment` on my system but it's not happening, I'm getting this instead:

```
$ npm install redis;npm install moment
/home/ron
└─┬ redis@2.8.0 
  ├── double-ended-queue@2.1.0-0 
  ├── redis-commands@1.4.0 
  └── redis-parser@2.6.0 

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/ron/package.json'
npm WARN ron No description
npm WARN ron No repository field.
npm WARN ron No README data
npm WARN ron No license field.
/home/ron
├── moment@2.22.2 
└── redis@2.8.0 

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/ron/package.json'
npm WARN ron No description
npm WARN ron No repository field.
npm WARN ron No README data
npm WARN ron No license field.
```

and I've tried with `sudo` too but got the same result... How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to run `npm init`. You have to create package.json file first.

You can find more details here: 
https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-a-package-json-file

Answer (score 1):

Have you created a `package.json` file? Maybe I Think run this command first again.

```
LPB_Tandn_IT:~ tannetto$ npm init
```

This is command creates a package.json file in your folder.

Then run,

```
LPB_Tandn_IT:~ tannetto$ npm install redis --save
```

The `--save` ensures your module is saved as a dependency in your `package.json` file.

I hope you will find this article useful and this works.